# How print content about Response Content Type Json?

Tags: javascript, json, httpresponse, content-type

hello sorry for the question but i don't know like to do what i want...

If i run this link https://api.onwater.io/api/v1/results/10,10 API say if this point (latitude 10°N; longitude 10°E) is in water or land.

the result in this case is:

```
{"lat":9.999237824938984,"lon":10.000257977613291,"water":false}
```

How i can to print value's `water` ??

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can I assume that you retrieve the data from AJAX request?

Comment: I hope... can yoy show me an example or link ? Thanks in advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for an AJAX Call you can do it with pure JS like this

```js
function callAjax() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {   // XMLHttpRequest.DONE == 4
           if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
               var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
               document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML =           response.water;
           }
           else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
              alert('There was an error 400');
           }
           else {
               alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
           }
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.onwater.io/api/v1/results/10,10", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
callAjax();
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Using jquery would be like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.onwater.io/api/v1/results/10,10",
    context: document.body,
    success: function(data){
     console.log(data.water);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally you could access it by its property name:

```js
const response = {"lat":9.999237824938984,"lon":10.000257977613291,"water":false}

console.log(response.water);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you're retrieving the data through AJAX

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){
        // parse the response to object
        var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        // print it out (obj.water and obj['water'] produces the same result)
        alert(obj.water);
        console.log(obj['water']); // prints it in console
    }
};
xhr.open("GET", "https://api.onwater.io/api/v1/results/10,10", true);
xhr.send();
```

You can learn more about AJAX [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp).